# Finding number of integral solutions

Tags: permutations, systems-of-equations, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

I am really getting confused in this question.

Number of integral solutions of the equation.

$x_1x_2x_3x_4=770$
options-

1. $2^{11}$
2. $2^{10}$
3. $4^4$
4. $5^5$

I attemtemted it by saying that $7*11*5*2=770$

so solutions should be $4!$
then we can say $77*5*2*1=770$
so $4!$

and $77*10*1*1=770$
so $4!/2$

and then $770*1*1*1=770$
so $4!/3!$

now multiplying them i get $27648$.
i am sure i have made a big mistage here but i dont know what.
please help

Comment: Let me know if I edited something poorly.

Comment: no its fine:) i just want the question answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four buckets, $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$, and four numbers, $2, 5, 7, 11$, to put in those buckets. As the buckets are ordered, the numbers unique, and you can put several numbers into the same bucket, there's $4^4$ ways of performing this task.

However, you're interested in *inegral* solution, so you ought to consider positive *and* negative. Let us choose signs of $x_1, \dots, x_4$. If we have chosen the signs of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, then the sign of $x_4$ is uniquely determined. There is $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2$ ways of choosing the signs of $x_1, \dots x_3$.

That is, the answer should be $4^4\cdot 2^3 = 2^{11}$.

Comment: why are there 4^4 ways of putting the numbers in 4 buckets. it should be 4! ways ? shouldnt it be 4! ways? if repetition was allowed the for eg 2*2*2*2 is not 770 so it should be 4!? the rest i have understood.

Comment: You can put several numbers into the same bucket, so you have 4 choices of buckets for each number. If you could only put 1 number in each bucket, then the answer would be $4!$ (4 choices for the first number, 3 choices for the second, etc..)

Comment: I added that part to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**  $2\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 = 770 \to 4! = 24$

**Case 2:** $10\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4!$

**Case 3:** $14\cdot 5 \cdot 11\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4!$

**Case 4:** $22 \cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4!$

**Case 5:** $35 \cdot 2\cdot 11\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4!$

**Case 6:** $55 \cdot 2\cdot 7\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4!$

**Case 7:** $77\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4!$

**Case 8:** $70\cdot 11\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4\cdot 3 = 12$

**Case 9:** $110\cdot 7\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4\cdot 3 = 12$

**Case 10:** $154\cdot 5\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4\cdot 3 = 12$

**Case 11:** $385\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4\cdot 3 = 12$

**Case 12:** $770\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 770 \to 4$.

Thus the total number of solutions is: $7\cdot 24 + 4\cdot 12 + 4 = 220$

Comment: The general idea works, a little tedious. Some are left out like  $110, 7,1,1$ and others like that. And they may really mean integers, as in allowing negatives.

Comment: no but this is too long a method and i dont think this is giving the right answer. Please give me a method which give the correct answer. what if it is x1x2x3x4x5x6x7=something                   then this method cant be applicable

Comment: according to your answer it comes out to be 216 which is wrong

Comment: I was in the middle of editing when you wrote your comments.

Comment: even 220 is wrong its not in the options.

Answer (score 0):

770=$7\cdot11\cdot2\cdot5$

for, $x_1x_2x_3x_4$we can place 5,7,2 and 11 all in $4 \choose 1$ ways.

So total no of solutions are $4 \choose 1$$4 \choose 1$$4 \choose 1$$4 \choose 1$=$4^4$

Comment: why are there 4^4 ways of putting the numbers in 4 buckets. it should be 4! ways ? shouldnt it be 4! ways? if repetition was allowed the for eg 2*2*2*2 is not 770 so it should be 4!?